# Valid a Form: Return false not possible / Always starts the action of the form

Tags: javascript, html

I use a form to submit some data to an API. Further, I use a recaptcha to avoid bots.

My Problem:

If the user inputs a wrong sum, he gets an error alert. But after the error alert, the script always performs "action="www.test.de", so the user doesn´t get a chance to correct the input.
`return false` also doesn´t work.

Can someone point out the error?

The Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
        var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
        var c = a + b
        function DrawBotBoot() {
            document.write("Was ergibt " + a + " + " + b + "? ");
            document.write("<br/><input id='BotBootInput' type='text' maxlength='2' size='2'/><br/>");
        }

        function ValidBotBoot() {
            var d = document.getElementById('BotBootInput').value;
            if(d == c)
                $('#test_form').submit(function(evt) {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    var uvSubdomain = "test";
                    var uvKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
                    var message = $('#message').val();
                    var subject = $('#subject').val();
                    var name = $('#name').val();
                    var email = $('#email').val();
                    $.jsonp({
                        url : 'https://' + uvSubdomain + '.test/tickets/create_via_jsonp.json?callback=?',
                        data : {
                            client : uvKey,
                            ticket : {
                                message : message,
                                subject : ("Anfrage via Landingpage test.de")
                            },
                            name : name,
                            email : email
                        },
                        success : function(data) {
                            alert('Herzlichen Dank für Ihre Mitteilung! Wir werden uns umgehend bei Ihnen melden.');
                            window.open('index.html', '_self', false)
                        },
                        error : function(d, msg) {
                            alert("Leider konnte die Mitteilung nicht übermittelt werden.");
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            else
                alert('Falsches Ergebnis')
            document.contact.BotBootInput.focus();
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="contact_form">
                            <form id="test_form" name="contact" method="post" action="https://www.test.de">
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" class="span3" />
                                <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" class="span3" />
                                <label for="message">Mittteilung</label>
                                <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                                <div>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">DrawBotBoot()</script>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary"  onclick="ValidBotBoot()">
                                        Senden
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

Comment: I am confused what behavior you want on button click? I saw you are binding submit button on click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
else {
    alert('Falsches Ergebnis')
    document.contact.BotBootInput.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share a JSFiddle.net example?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to simply discard the event:
1. return `false` and  from called function and
2. use `return` keyword just before function name.

So, finally value of `onclick` attribute should be:

```
onclick="return ValidBotBoot()"
```

Comment: If I insert return: <button class="btn btn-large btn-warning"  onclick="return ValidBotBoot()"> my problem ist solved. But now, there is another problem: the part if(d == c)...-part doesn´t work anymore...